# When factor rotation method allows correlation between factors, would it yield a simpler structure?

Tags: factor-analysis

I read in many resources that the answer is "yes", but it's quite counter-intuitive. If two factors are correlated, a manifest variable would load on both factors right?

Can someone explain either mathematically or intuitively? Thank you so much!

Comment: When you say 'simpler structure' do you mean simple structure as it is usually used in factor analysis?  I think the answer is that it depends.

Comment: Similar comment to @JeremyMIles - can you define what "simple" means in this context? A direct answer to one of you questions is that there is no reason that correlation among latent variables would necessitate cross-loadings.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! @JeremyMiles "Simple structure" in this context means "A pattern of loadings where each item loads strongly on only one of the factors, and much more weakly on the other factors".

Comment: @MattBarstead "Simple structure" in this context means "A pattern of loadings where each item loads strongly on only one of the factors, and much more weakly on the other factors". Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Responding to: "If two factors are correlated, a manifest variable would load on both factors right?" I would say a better way to think of this is that if two factors are correlated, there is a pathway in the model that would allow for some correlation between the manifest variables and each factor (as well as each other). That is not the same thing as allowing observed variables to cross load though.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know whether this really helps you; it is a somehow q&d patched older answer to some question here (see the mathjax-symbols in the text), which I've just a bit cleaned for your question's requirements - I hope this helps for the intuition. If this is not your problem, or if it is more obfuscating than clearing, then simply forget it or ask or comment. See here: http://go.helms-net.de/stat/fa/stats_PCA.pdf